# Using dotPeek, I would like to see the full structure of the UnityEngine namespace

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, namespaces, dotpeek

When wondering how the source code of the `.NET API` is implemented, I check the `mscorlib` of `dotPeek`.

I recently started studying `Unity`, and I'm curious about the inside of the `UnityEngine` namespae.

```cs
using UnityEngine; // This one!
```

How can I check the inside of `UnityEngine` namespace in `dotPeek`?

Here's what I've tried:

- I looked for `MSDN API Browser` but couldn't find it.
- I downloaded and decompiled `UnityEngine.dll`, but it wasn't what I want.
- I downloaded the `Unity Engine decompiled file` from GitHub, but it was the engine itself, not the namespace.
- I searched the `official Unity website`, but could only find an explanation of the terminology.

Currently I am using the `Go to definition` method provided by Visual Studio 2022.

It's a really great feature, but it's a pity because it can only be used when there is a written source code.

I really desperately want your help. Thanks for reading.

Comment: Multiple libraries can declare types (classes, etc.) within the same namespace. In fact, you could write the following code in your own project: `namespace UnityEngine { public class MyClass { } }` and then `MyClass` would be available anywhere where you have using UnityEngine;. I don't know about Unity, but it's entirely possible that the code you're looking for isn't contained in a single assembly. Unless Unity is open source, the only way you can sort of see the code is to decompile the libraries.

Comment: Have you looked through the source code that unity has made available?  [Here is the gitHub](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference)  It isn't everything, but if you are looking for something in particular, it is a useful resource.

Comment: [Unity Scripting API](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/api/index.html)

Comment: @quaabaam oops.. docs were there... Thank you.

Comment: @quaabaam lol ^^

Comment: You can try to take a look at https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UsingDLL.html,
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Unity Scripting Engine [is documented](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/). That should be enough to do what you need for game development. Stuff like [RigidBody](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.html) can be found unter `UnityEngine` and then `Classes`.